# Saved HTML page different from current view

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, save

**Context:** I remember visiting a web page that I "Saved As" on my Desktop and being surprised that my local copy was really different from the original one: a lot of the content was missing.

**Question:** Does anyone knows how to reproduce this behaviour (Saved page "escaping" some elements on the page)?

I might have been tired/confused and make a mistake while saving. So "You've been dreaming, it's impossible" can be the correct answer!

Thanks a lot for your help.
Nicolas

Comment: `save as` saves what got sent to the browser when you ORIGINALLY requested the page. It will NOT contain any modifications made to the page via javascript, ajax calls, blah blah blah. If you awnt the "live" version of the page, you'll have to use a DOM inspector to extract a copy of the live DOM tree.

Comment: @MarcB, are you sure? I just tried this example on local server [link](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_first). When I "save as" the page after loading AJAX content I get the live version and not the original requested page.

Answer (score 0):

So what you are saying is that the copy you saved to the desktop was different to the original?  if so then this is ether because it did not save properly or you saved the desktop copy halfway through completing the page, and the direct save still went to the original.  if this is not it then I don't know.  Hope this helps :)